# Symmetric encryption which returns specific character set and specific length

Tags: c#, encryption, rijndael

I use this code below to encrypt and decrypt a string, but it returns a value including special characters and length of returned value is not specific.

I want to use this to generate a serial key, so is it possible to turn result to specific length and specific character set like A-Z,0-9 ?

```
static readonly string PasswordHash = "P@@Sw0rd";
static readonly string SaltKey = "S@LT&KEY";
static readonly string VIKey = "@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8";


public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
{
    byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

    byte[] keyBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PasswordHash, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltKey)).GetBytes(256 / 8);
    var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged() { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros };
    var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(VIKey));

    byte[] cipherTextBytes;

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            cryptoStream.Close();
        }
        memoryStream.Close();
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
}

public static string Decrypt(string encryptedText)
{
    byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
    byte[] keyBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PasswordHash, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltKey)).GetBytes(256 / 8);
    var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged() { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.None };

    var decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(VIKey));
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
    var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];

    int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
    memoryStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount).TrimEnd("\0".ToCharArray());
}
```

Comment: Rolled back, please don't adjust your code to match the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The two padding modes do not match. Especially `PaddingMode.None` does not make sense if your data is not block-aligned.

`PaddingMode.Zeros` also does not make sense because it causes the padding to be not removable.

It seems you have fiddled with settings until it seemed to work. That is very dangerous with cryptography. It is also an unsound development practice in general.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, i edited the question and use PaddingMode.PKCS7 instead of None and Zeros.

Comment: You're also reading the wrong length. Use the debugger and validate all values at runtime.